# What is the purpose of the 'proc' parameter in Marshal::load?

Tags: ruby, deserialization, unmarshalling, proc

I have looked for resources which explain its purpose. I couldn't find any real world implementations either.

Below is the extract from Ruby's [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Marshal.html):

> **load( source [, proc] ) → obj** Returns the result of converting the
> serialized data in source into a Ruby object (possibly with associated
> subordinate objects). source may be either an instance of IO or an
> object that responds to to_str. If proc is specified, each object will
> be passed to the proc, as the object is being deserialized.

I would appreciate an example of its usage, or at least direct me to some resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the proc is invoked by doing something like:

```
irb(main):030:0> Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a:1), lambda { |x| p [self,x]; x })
[main, :a]
[main, 1]
[main, {:a=>1}]
=> {:a=>1}
```

When used with a marshalled string, the proc is for some reason invoked twice.

```
irb(main):031:0> Marshal.load(Marshal.dump('a'), lambda { |x| p [self,x]; x })
[main, "a"]
[main, true]
=> "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Transformation of Deserialized Objects

A general use case is that you want to perform some action or transformation on the object you're deserializing. For example, using some Ruby 2.7.1 shortcuts:

```
Marshal.load Marshal.dump("abc"), ->{ _1.to_s.upcase }
#=> "ABC"
```

This doesn't add much value when deserializing a single object, but could be very useful if you're handling dumped objects in bulk. I can't think of a pragmatic use case where you couldn't transform *after* deserializing, but Ruby is full of useful tools for handling things without intermediate steps. This seems to be one of them.

### Possible Bug: Procs Appear to Run Twice but Return Once

In the example above, I coerce the first positional argument to a string because otherwise I get a NoMethodError on one of the two passes this is making through the lambda. You can sort of unpack what's going on (but perhaps not why) as follows:

```
prc = proc { |obj| pp obj }
Marshal.load Marshal.dump("abc"), prc
```

> ```
> "abc"
> true
> #=> "abc"
> ```

For whatever reason, the body of a Proc or lambda is called twice, but only *returns* the first pass. The problem occurs when the second invocation raises a NoMethodError exception when called on TrueClass, so the call never returns a value.

Another way to handle this is to explicitly handle the exception, e.g.:

```
prc = proc { |obj| obj.upcase rescue NoMethodError }
```

or to avoid invoking methods on `true`:

```
prc = proc { |obj| obj.upcase unless obj == true }
```

While I can explain *what* is going on, and how to work around it, I can't tell you *why* invoking with a proc-like object behaves this way. That's a question for the Ruby Core Team, or fodder for the [Ruby bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/).